# SlideItMoo control-buttons do not show up in IE9

Tags: mootools

I'm using the SlideItMoo-Script from this site:

http://www.php-help.ro/examples/slideitmoo_1.1/

As you can see in the first example (Demo 1), there is an image slider with 3 images that get slided if you click on one of the controls to the left and right.

When I open the same page with IE9, the Demo 1 is displayed as a div with large height, all elements are showing up and the controls are totally missing.

As I'm using this script on several sites I would appreciate any help to solve this problem. Does anyone has any tipps for me?

EDIT: additional informations:

Via the IE9-Developer-Tools I get the folowwong javascript-error:

```
SCRIPT5022: DOM Exception: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR (5) 
mootools-1.2.1-core.js, Zeile 117 Zeichen 71
```

On Line 117 | 71 the following code is given:

```
return moo.element(this.createElement(A)
```

Comment: I tried to update to the mootools-script to version 1.4.5, but this didn't work for me...with this script the SlideItMoo-script gets crashed

Comment: the issue only appears when I'm using IE9-browser-mode, in IE7- and IE8-browser-mode everything is fine, as it is in IE9-campatibility-mode...only in IE9-browser-mode the controls are missing...

Comment: I finally found a working site with a running example of the SlideItMoo-Script in IE9: http://www.htmldrive.net/items/demo/723/SlideItMoo-v1.1-multiple-image-slider...so I adapted the code from there and implemented it in my site...now everything is working...